# Space between lines

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing

I try to typeset title pages and use LARGE and bold for this. The problem is that the lines seem to be too close to each other. I think it looks bad. Is this the way it is supposed to be? Is there a better way to do this?

```
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE\bf An \textit{a priori} Typology of Sentential Negation from an HPSG Perspective}\\[\baselineskip]

\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Edit: OK what I really wanted isa title page like the stuff below. I wanted to have space between the lines. This was the reason for baselineskip. And the whole reason for messing around with the font sizes are the descriptions by google scholar that tell pdf producers to use fonts in different sizes for title and author and rest.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn,draft]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE\bf An \textit{a priori} Typology of Sentential Negation from\\[1mm] an HPSG Perspective}\\[\baselineskip]

{\large Joshua Crowgey}\\[\baselineskip]
University of Washington\\[3\baselineskip]

                Proceedings of the HPSG 2012 Conference\\[\baselineskip]

Department of Linguistics, Chungnam National University Daejeon, South Korea\\[\baselineskip]

                        Stefan M{\"u}ller (Editor)\\[\baselineskip]

                                2012\\[\baselineskip]

                          CSLI Publications\\[\baselineskip]

              http://csli-publications.stanford.edu/

\end{center}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: related (but not quite duplicate) questions: [Incorrect line spacing when using \Large in a center environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53347), [Inconsistent line spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36454).  i've added the tag [line-spacing] for better retrieval.

Comment: I've added an implementation of your updated post. The concepts still remain the same - using `\par` whenever you're in a group that has localized font formatting, and adding whitespace to simulate `\par`. Adding `\bigskip` or `\medskip` of `\vspace*{3\bigskipamount}` are just other ways of increasing the whitespace between document elements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Insert `\par` inside the `{\LARGE...}` group and remove the line break at the end, since "There's no line here to end." Or, just drop the group formatting entirely, letting the font selection be scoped by the `center` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE\bfseries An \textit{a priori} Typology of Sentential Negation from an HPSG Perspective}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\LARGE\bfseries An \textit{a priori} Typology of Sentential Negation from an HPSG Perspective
\end{center}

\end{document}​
```

The motivation here is that TeX only sets a paragraph once it's fully read it. So, without a blank line or an indication like `\par` the paragraph isn't set correctly with the change in `\baselineskip`.

Please note that the `\it`, `\bf`, etc. font macros are deprecated because
they do not use the new font selection scheme introduced with LaTeX2e.
Please use `{\itshape ..}`, `{\bfseries ..}` or `\textit{..}`, `\textbf{..}` instead.
See [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/5764)
and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)
for more information.

---

With your updated post, here are some things to try, using the concepts described above:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,fleqn,draft]{article}
\usepackage{url}% http://ctan.org/pkg/url
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  {\LARGE\bf An \textit{a priori} Typology of Sentential Negation from\par an HPSG Perspective\par}

  \bigskip

  {\large Joshua Crowgey\par}
  University of Washington

  \vspace*{3\bigskipamount}

  Proceedings of the HPSG 2012 Conference

  \bigskip

  Department of Linguistics, Chungnam National University Daejeon, South Korea

  \medskip

  Stefan M{\"u}ller (Editor)

  \medskip

  2012

  \medskip

  CSLI Publications

  \medskip

  \url{http://csli-publications.stanford.edu/}
\end{center}

\newpage

\end{document}​
```

Comment: or just remove the `{}` group and let `LARGE` be scoped by the `center` environment which will insert the paragraph end automatically.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks. That's a tad cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

1. Add `\usepackage{setspace}`.
2. To change line spacing for whole document use `\setstretch{baselinestretch}`. For some custom text use environment: `\begin{spacing}{2.5} ... \end{spacing}`.

That's, I think, what's you need.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the document class you are using but you can also use the `\title{}`. And see [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc)

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{\textbf{\LARGE An \emph{a priori} Typology of Sentential Negation from an HPSG Perspective}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\vspace{-3\baselineskip} % If you wish to remove the space for date and author
Start of the text part .... 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've got a similar problem in a book document class for just two centered lines in a rather long text. Something like this: \begin{center} blah blah blah \\ blah blah blah \end{center} perhaps the double slash is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change only space between two lines, you can write:

```
first line\\[-1ex]
second line
```

It's very useful in the figures.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!