# Using multiple newlines (\\) within LARGE block

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I am trying to typeset a long title using a `{\LARGE ...}`-Block.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
    {\LARGE Very \\ Long \\ Title}
\end{document}
```

And the output of (latex + dvips + ps2pdf):

[image: Output of the above example code]

Question: How do I remove the vertical space between the first and the second line?

Info: If I use a `{\normalsize...}`-Block the spacing between the lines is as expected (equal vertical space between first and second line and between second and third line.

Comment: Add a `\par` after `Title`.

Comment: You don't want to remove the space between the first and second lines, but rather add space between the second and third lines.

Comment: I don't get that output at all. As is, I get three lines that are too close together. Adding the `\par` recommended by Harish Kumar, I get equally spaced lines with the correct `\baselineskip`. Did you leave something out of your MWE?

Comment: The above image is the actual result of the above code on my setup (Windows, MikTex) otherwise I wouldn't have added the image.

Comment: related: [Inconsistent line spacing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36454/579) and [Incorrect line spacing when using \Large in a center environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53347/579).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to put the title into a `flushleft`, `center` or `flushright` environment as you desire the alignment.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\LARGE Very \\ Long \\ Title
\end{flushleft}
\begin{center}
\LARGE Very \\ Long \\ Title
\end{center}
\begin{flushright}
\LARGE Very \\ Long \\ Title
\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

[image]