# too much space with tabto and enumitem

Tags: spacing, enumitem, tabto

The MWE below indicates the problem. The final item, number 6, isn't aligned correctly (it is pushed some extra space to the right!). This is also the case when I change the number of tabs to 2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}

\NumTabs{3}
\begin{description*}[before={\noindent},itemjoin={\tab}]
\item {1.} 
\item {2.} 
\item {3.} 
\item {4.} 
\item {5.} 
\item {6.} 
\end{description*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at the `tasks` package (part of [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets/)). My answer to [How can I make two columns in two columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107278/5049) shows an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Insert `after={\hfill}` in the `description*` options.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}

\NumTabs{3}
\begin{description*}[before={\noindent},itemjoin={\tab},after={\hfill}]
\item {1.}
\item {2.}
\item {3.}
\item {4.}
\item {5.}
\item {6.}
\end{description*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

To be able to do what you ask in the comment, we need to issue `\hfill\par` before the closing brace, otherwise the paragraph is not ended. For explanations see, for example, [Incorrect line spacing when using \Large in a center environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53347/27635).

This can be done with the help of the `etoolbox` package and the line

```
\AfterEndEnvironment{description*}{\hfill\par}
```

that adds `\hfill\par` after `description*` has ended.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{description*}{\hfill\par}

\begin{document}

{\tiny\NumTabs{3}
\begin{description*}[before={\noindent},itemjoin={\tab},after={\hfill}]
\item {1.}
\item {2.}
\item {3.}
\item {4.}
\item {5.}
\item {6.}
\end{description*}}
\bigskip

\NumTabs{3}
\begin{description*}[before={\noindent},itemjoin={\tab},after={\hfill}]
\item {1.}
\item {2.}
\item {3.}
\item {4.}
\item {5.}
\item {6.}
\end{description*}
\bigskip

{\Huge\NumTabs{3}
\begin{description*}[before={\noindent},itemjoin={\tab},after={\hfill}]
\item {1.}
\item {2.}
\item {3.}
\item {4.}
\item {5.}
\item {6.}
\end{description*}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This works! When I then wrapped a `{\tiny ...}` around it all, that is: `{\tiny\NumTabs{3}...\end{description*}}`, again I get strange behaviour with the final \item.

Comment: @Geoff I've added a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to an enumerated list in two or three columns is the `multienum` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multienum}
\begin{document}

\begin{multienumerate}
\mitemxxx{One}{Two}{Three}
\mitemxxx{Four}{Five}{Six}
\end{multienumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]